# iPhone: random "image of the day" type service?

Tags: iphone, xml, image, rss, random

The iPhone makes it really simple to snarf down an image from the web; you can turn a URL into a `UIImage` in one line of code.  So I'd like to enable my app (an educational puzzle game... my first!) to download some random images to make it more interesting and dynamic.

I thought about using [Kodak's image of the day](http://feeds2.feedburner.com/KodakPictureOfTheDay) RSS feed, but I'm having quite a time figuring out how to parse it.  Rather than being a simple list of image URLs, it seems to reference a bunch of "jhtml" URLs, which run Javascript to display the images in your RSS reader.  Is this intentionally obfuscated, or am I missing some basic step to parse this?

I also tried the [Astronomy Picture of the Day](http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/), via [this](http://feed://www.acme.com/jef/apod/rss.xml) RSS feed, but it's just the original page's HTML stuffed into CDATA... ugh.

So I guess this is really two questions:

1. Is there a simple way to parse these feeds to actually get at the JPG URLs on the iPhone?
2. Is there a better source for "picture of the day" type images?

PS: I'm using NSXMLParser, which I learned to use [here](http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html).

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to write a parser for astronomy picture of the day's html - it only has a single IMG tag (for now).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going with something that has an API, perhaps the Flickr "Interestingness" feed:

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.interestingness.getList.html

There is an objective-C library written to help with accessing Flickr but not sure if this API call is included:

http://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr/tree/master

Comment: Thanks for the API link.  But I'm guessing that they'd consider my use of this API commercial (it will be sold in the app store).  Still, a good thing to consider.